# firebase with react native, too slow

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I use firebase 3.4.1 and react-native 0.34.1.

I was amazed that receiving retrieved data is very slow from firebase.

This is my react-native test code.

```
class test1 extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();

        let config = {
            apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            authDomain: "yyyyyyyy.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://zzzzzz.firebaseio.com",
        };

        Firebase.initializeApp(config);

        this.rootRef = Firebase.database().ref();
        this.postRef = this.rootRef.child('posts');

        this.state = {
           like : 'like : ',
           comment : 'comment : ',
        };

    componentWillMount(){
        console.debug('componentWillMount');
        let num = 0;
        let time = new Date().getTime();
        this.postRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(10).once('value')
        .then((postsnap) => {
            console.debug(new Date().getTime() - time);
            postsnap.forEach((postItem) => {
               console.debug(num++);
               console.debug(new Date().getTime() - time);
               this.setState({
                  like : this.state.like + postItem.child('like').numChildren() + ', ',
                  comment : this.state.comment + postItem.child('comment').numChildren() + ', ',
               });
            });
         });
     }

     render() {
         return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                {this.state.like}
                </Text>
                <Text>
                {this.state.comment}
                </Text>
            </View>
         );
     }
}
```

My firebase database's structure is very simple, 
'rootref' has just 6 'posts'.

```
componentWillMount
8760
0
8761
1
8766
2
8767
3
8768
4
8769
5
8772
```

Do you guys have any idea for faster retrieving data from firebase?

Comment: Data retrieval performance is usually a combination of the amount of data you request and then dividing that by the bandwidth you have available. It could be that your React Native setup is having problems, but there is nothing we can do for that. Can you set up a regular React jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: it seem to be connection problem,.. i think..
there is no cost time after connection.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot better to use a singleton pattern to get the `Reference`. Instead of calling `Firebase.initializeApp` everytime, You make it global by putting it in a seperated module. And, then, you export the instantiated reference to `Firebase.database().ref()`. And use it throughout the app lifetime.

Anyway, I have found that, even I use this approach, the minimum loading time I got for 1 node query (`node/key`) are ~200 milliseconds, which is really slow.